# Tooltip misplaced inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-resource

The following shows the tooltip text in the right place:

```
  %a{:href => "http://google.com/"}
    %span{:tooltip => "TEST"}
      = "test"
```

The following shows the tooltip half a screen below (increasing distance for each element)

```
%div{:"ng-repeat" => "point in points"}
  %a{:href => "http://google.com/"}
    %span{:tooltip => "TEST"}
      = "test"
```

It's written in HAML, so in plain HTML the last two lines look like this: `<span tooltip="TEST">test</span>`.

The `points` are fetched using [Rails $Resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource), but I get the same problem when I use the regular $resource.

I'm using the tooltip directive from [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip). The application is built in Ruby on Rails 4.0 and uses the angularjs-rails gem (unstable).

My best guess is that the CSS on my site is somehow too complex and that I need to find a way to reprocesses these tooltips after loading.

Comment: As with any AngularJS directive you would have to $compile it to take effect.

Comment: have you included ui.bootsrap in your module dependency

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal yes I did. I don't think the tooltip would work in the first example if I hadn't.
@pkozlowski.opensource I'm not really sure how to do that. Should I add something to my `$scope.points.then (points) ->` method in my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add this below my `app = angular.module(...)` line:

```
app.config( function ( $tooltipProvider ) {
  $tooltipProvider.options({appendToBody: true});
});
```

I'm not sure what's going on here, but it has something to do with https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/254 and perhaps also https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/139.